# Correct function(my_deamon_fun()) is not being profiled correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, twisted, memory-profiling, twisted.web

We've instrumented method: my_daemon_fun()) by using python memory-profiler and guppy.

To profile the code all I need to do is:

```
 STEP#1 -> decorate the my_daemon_fun() with "profile" decorator   
 STEP#2 -> start memory profiling 
 STEP#3 -> end memory profiling
```

Something like this:

```
@profile                                               => STEP#1    
@inlineCallbacks
def my_daemon_fun(self):
    """
    Monitor my daemons
    """
    if self.running == True:
        try:
            hp = hpy()                                 => STEP#2
            before = hp.heap()
            yield self._lock.acquire()
            .....
            if ((x_running == False) or (b_running == False)):
                log.error('Daemons are not running, restarting...')
                yield self._restart_daemons()
        except:
            log.exception('Exception restarting daemons')
        finally:
            yield self._lock.release()
            reactor.callLater(MY_DAEMON_MONITOR_INTERVAL, self.my_daemon_fun)
            after = hp.heap()                         => STEP#3
            leftover = after - before
```

Now we run the script to call method: my_daemon_fun().
After running the script though we see memory profiling happening but the function being profiled is **not** the one we decorated with @profile:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment      Line Contents
1176     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       def unwindGenerator(*args, **kwargs):
1177     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           try:
1178     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               gen = f(*args, **kwargs)
1183     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           if not isinstance(gen, types.GeneratorType):
1187     42.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
```

I am doubting that **generator** or **inlineCallback** decorator is prohibiting the correct code from getting profiled.

I am investigating why the actual function(i.e.  my_daemon_fun()) was not profiled? 
Meanwhile if you can help us here that would be great.

Comment: is it possible to profile the function without the decorator @inlineCallbacks, or at least swap the order of the decorations, i.e. @inlineCallbacks@profile ?

Comment: @FabianPedregosa I already tried that but with that I am not seeing any profiling in the logs. No memory usage is being recorded.

Comment: What did not work, removing @inlineCallbacks or reverting the order?

Comment: @FabianPedregosa Reverting the order did not had any impact.. Basically no memory profiling was done. If we remove inlineCallbacks then it does work. But we can't remove inlineCallbacks.

Comment: I'm afraid that it won't work on a decorated function. It need to have access to the code inside the function, and since a decorator wraps that function, memory_profiler has no longer access to the original function ...